# how to disable a particular option in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I have a select field in sencha touch as below.

```
 var filter = new Ext.form.Select({
     options: [
        { text: 'Availability', value: 'Availability' },
        { text: 'Price', value: 'Price' },
        { text: 'Proximity', value: 'Proximity' }
        ],
     id:'FilterSelect'
     label: 'Filter By'
 });
```

I  would like to know how to disable or hide a particular option value, as on some events I need to hide/disable the **"Proximity option"** and vice versa.

Comment: Just a guess: have you tried giving the option an `itemId`, and querying for it, and then calling `hide()` on it?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to change the options, simply call setOptions() like this:

```
filter.setOptions([ 
    { text: 'Availability', value: 'Availability' }, 
    { text: 'Price', value: 'Price' }
]);
```

The docs have an additional example: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Select